# Migrating disqus comments without identifier to new one with identifier

Tags: disqus

So that previous threads have no identifier and i changed it to have identifier for each article, Now previous  comments wont show.

Didn't find any way to migrate old comments without identifier to new system with identifier.

Is there a way to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

- Ensure your article shows the same thread no matter what URL is used to access the article
- Then add the identifier to the embed code at your article
- Right after that, revisit your article via its primary URL

Here is why I think that should work based on what worked for me just a short while ago:

I have 2 URLs for a page of mine that embeds a disqus thread, call them URLs A and B.
I did not set `disqus_url` or `disqus_identifier` from the start.

People usually reach my page using URL B and they already posted some comments, meaning the page did not show any of those comments when accessed via URL A.
However, URL A was supposed to be the primary one for my page, so I used the URL mapper from the migration tools of the disqus admin. It says one should wait a while until the mappings start to have an effect. After a few minutes, though, I visited my page via URL A, and all the comments where there already. I did not visit my page via URL B again right after that.

Then, I set `disqus_url` to URL A *and* `disqus_identifier` to some unique value that pertains to my page. After that, I revisited my page via URL A. All the comments where still there. Then, I visited the page via URL B, and the same comments where still there.

After this, I unset `disqus_url` since you normally only need it if you did not set `disqus_identifier`. Revisiting my page via both URLs still showed the same comments (I did not try posting a comment after this, but I assume it would still show up everywhere).

Good luck!

Comment: Worked, but decided to don't use DISQUS anymore. They are not responsible for anything and have a very weak support. Also DISQUS has so limited configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be able to do it using their API:

https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/update/

Will be trying this at some point over the next few days and post some details, if I get it working (or someone else is welcome to if they get there first!)